# абсолютное позиционирование блока, css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу отпозиционировать блок (item) относительно именно тега body. Проблема в том, что элементы block__2 и block__3 имеют свойство position:relative; И получается что item подвязывается к block__3. item нельзя перемещать непосредственно в обертку body, вот так:

```
<body>
    <div class="item">Важный блок</div>
</body>
```

Моя структура странички:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="block__1">
    <div class="block__2">
      <div class="block__3">
        <div class="item">Важный блок</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а покажите css свой

Comment: ну так уберите у блоков 2 и 3 `position:relative`. Нельзя убрать - переопределите на `static`

Comment: так свойство position:relative в основном и используется для того чтобы позиционировать дочерние элементы относительно блока к кому это свойство применено. Т.е. тут либо уберите это свойство у родителя, либо поместите свой важный блок вне родителя, либо используйте у важного блока свойство position: fixed, что будет иметь немного другое поведение чем absolute, но позиционировать всегда будет относительно body. Других вариантов я не вижу и смею предположить, что их просто нет.